# Why is the 555 timer getting destroyed instantaneously?

Tags: 555

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYaoaL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was working on a simple flyback driver that uses an astable oscillator to give a signal to the MOSFET which would drive the flyback. Even though the signal generator looks extremely fine and could generate a frequency from 10k to 0.1±Mhz, upto 5.7V with variable duty cycle, as soon as the drain of the GaN FET is connected to the primary coil it gives s spark and kills the timer.

My attempt was to isolate the timer from the GaN (as shown in the circuit) with a BJT which was failure because the BJT was working properly even after the timer is fried.

I also tried adding a resistor to the gate of the FET which worsend the instantaneous spark.

The thing that freaked me out was a circuit that uses the same logic (astable oscillator using transistor instead of 555 timer) worked great and I was able to increase the voltage through the gate by placing an inductor series to R4.

What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: You need a base resistor for Q1.

Comment: You probably also need a flyback diode for the transformer primary or something else is going to die.

Comment: Without snubber diode it's possible for large induced drain voltage to couple back to the gate (and 555's output) via gate-drain capacitance.

Comment: Let's add some decoupling capacitors to the shopping list, that transformer is going to kick VCC into orbit

Comment: @James sorry i forgot to include it there but I have already added it in my original circuit (I have edited the circuit)

Comment: @DKNguyen I am not sure why but I have tried adding and changing the polarity of  diode across the primary, it decreased the performance significantly  (using transistor as astable oscillator)

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu Well it does sap energy which is what it is designed to do. However, in your case you want that energy to go to the secondary so you do not want to sap energy unnecessarily. You just want to sap enough that the flyback voltage does not get high enough to cause damage. If you scope it and find it is okay then you are okay. If not, then you might try an RC snubber or bidirectional TVS. A diode (which can only be installed with anode on top and cathode on the bottom) in this schematic will clamp to the diode forward drop which is *very* conservatively and sap almost all the energy

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for the response, I will try the snubber or TVS ,Hopfuly get better result

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu The bi-TVS should be sized to what your power MOSFET source-drain can tolerate minus 12V. Because the flyback voltage induced on the coil will stack on top of the 12V and will be applied to your MOSFET. RC snubbers do not clamp to a hard voltage. Instead they slow down the pulse and spread the pulse out over time which decreases it's value (but sometimes the speed of the pulse is the problem and in that case a diode won't work and you need an RC). If you find your power MOSFET is misfiring, then that is indication you need an RC.

Comment: What is the transformer's turns ratio?

Comment: Is there a bypass on the supply?

Comment: You also need supply decoupling.

Answer (score 2):

-Define specs to ensure Flyback Xfmr is not saturating and specify DCR, L, I max.

common layout issues:

- Avoid loop current crosstalk by using twisted pair.
- Decrease current loop area of driver so that LM555 supply is not affected and does not share power/ground path to source. Twisted pairs preferred.
- use avalanche protect FET or add TVS across Vds and not to shared 12V, then RC filter to 555 Vcc may be necessary.
- add 15V TVS to Vgs.
- also compute resonant frequency from Coss=700 pF with Lp and DCR/X(f) and Q for full cycle and pulse width in choose f.

It is possible your duty cycle was too high and Flyback Tfmr saturated, overheated then arced when released.

In the future start with lower supply voltage and zero duty cycle then measure margins to failure.  (saturation, temp rise, peak voltage)

Answer (score 0):

I first thing I see is that you have no capacitor on pin5, when there's large current involved you need that bypass on the internal divider chain to keep the 555 stable. add 100nF MLCC between control voltage and ground (pin5 and pin1)

Make sure all of your grounds are well connected, this is not a not a circuit to build on solderless breadboard, especially  everything right of R7, needs to be soldered connections an connected directly to the supply and ground, not through solderless breadboard.